# Problems with sizes in Nemo Filemanager

Tags: nemo

I recently installed LM 19.2 and tried to change some preferences for the Nemo Filemanager.

In detail I changed the viewtype to list and fiddled around a little bit with the according sizes.

Actually I do have a 'strange' behaviour where I see different sizes in different folders and thoose folders do not take any changes I do within the preferences dialog.

Did I somehow changed the preferencess 'by folder'?

Is there any way to reset the preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, changes from the default in a folder view's settings within Nemo are stored on a per-folder basis by design. (Likewise for Nautilus, from which Nemo's derived, and Caja, also derived from Nautilus.)

To reset the preferences for a given folder you're currently viewing, there should be a `Reset View to Defaults` item in the `View` menu you can select.

To reset the previously saved per-folder view preferences for *all* folders, an answer to [How to reset all per-folder view settings in nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164551/how-to-reset-all-per-folder-view-settings-in-nautilus) suggests deleting the files in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`. According to an answer comment, it also seemed to work with Nemo. Both question and answer are over seven years old; so, if you try it, I'd recommend the precaution of *moving* the files in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata` rather than deleting them so you can recover in case something goes terribly wrong.

Comment: That did the trick ... Thx :-)